# Redshift query to identify users belonging to specific groups

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table (`user_group`) that looks like

```
user_id | group_id
--------+---------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 2
3       | 3
4       | 4
```

What's the best way to write a query that returns all users (`user_id`) who belong to some arbitrary subset of groups (`group_id`)?

Right now, my hacked query is as follows, where I just add/remove `WHERE` filters as needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM
    user_group
WHERE
    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_group WHERE group_id = 1)
    AND user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_group WHERE group_id = 5)
    ...
```

And, it feels like there should be a better way?

Comment: what is the output you'd like to see?

Comment: I only need `user_id` in my return set. And I want to filter the entire dataset for only users that are in all the `group_id`s I'm currently filtering for. For example, in the same query I list, I'm looking for all `user_id`s who are in *both* `group_id` 1 and `group_id` 5. Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_group
WHERE group_id IN (1, 5)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- number of groups in the `IN` list
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that better than my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Users who belong to *ANY* listed group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_id
FROM user_group
WHERE group_id in (1, 5)
```

Users who belong to *ALL* listed groups:

```
SELECT
  user_id
FROM user_group
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN group_id = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN group_id = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0
```